# javascript Unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

I am sending the following array from laravel 5 employeecontroller.php

```
$work_right_list_json = array(
            "test" => 123,
            "test2" => 345
        );
$work_right_list_json = json_encode($work_right_list_json);
return view(work_right , $data)->with("work_right_list_json" , $work_right_list_json);
```

Now I am catching the json string in work_rights_blade.php as follows :

```
var work_right_lists =  {{!!$work_right_list_json!!}};
```

I am getting the following error :

Unexpected token. From the chrome console, I can see the value as follows :The json string seems to be correct :

```
var work_right_lists =  {{"test":123,"test2":345}};
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Try removing the extra `{`, `}`

Comment: Why the double braces? That's not a valid object.

Comment: Thanks Chiru , Tushar. The double brace is blade syntax. It parses the php variable with this braces.

Comment: @Tanvir not in JavaScript it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. First the controller code was not correctly sending javascript :

```
$work_right_list_json = array(
            "test" => 123,
            "test2" => 345
        );
$work_right_list_json = json_encode($work_right_list_json);
return view(work_right , $data)->with("work_right_list_json" , $work_right_list_json);
```

In the javascript the code should be as follows :

```
var work_right_lists =  {!!"test":123,"test2":345!!};
```